# pandas: duplicate rows from small dataframe to large based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two sets of numerical data. One is much larger than the other. The same data from the smaller set applies to the larger set multiple times. For example, where B is the data I need to add to the larger set and C is the number of times each value A is referenced in the large set:

Small set:

```
A      B      C
123    1      2
456    5      3
```

Large set:

```
A      D
123    45
123    58
456    32
456    22
456    89
```

Desired output:

```
A      D      B
123    45     1
123    58     1 
456    32     5  
456    22     5
456    89     5
```

I have only seen questions wherein people want to remove duplicate fields; here it is important I match the value B so that result D can be better understood.

Comment: Look into pandas merge or join.

Answer (score 0):

you need, pd.merge

```
 df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='A')

 df=df[['A','D','B']]
```