# Pandas merge or join in smaller dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue whereby I have one long dataframe and one short dataframe, and I want to merge so that the shorter dataframe repeats itself to fill the length of the longer (left) df.

```
df1:

| Index  | Wafer | Chip | Value |
---------------------------------
| 0      | 1     | 32   | 0.99  |
| 1      | 1     | 33   | 0.89  |
| 2      | 1     | 39   | 0.96  |
| 3      | 2     | 32   | 0.81  |
| 4      | 2     | 33   | 0.87  |

df2:

| Index  |   x   |   y  |
-------------------------
| 0      |   1   |   3  |
| 1      |   2   |   2  |
| 2      |   1   |   6  |


df_combined:

| Index  | Wafer | Chip | Value |   x   |   y   |
-------------------------------------------------
| 0      | 1     | 32   | 0.99  |   1   |   3   |
| 1      | 1     | 33   | 0.89  |   2   |   2   |
| 2      | 1     | 39   | 0.96  |   1   |   6   |
| 3      | 2     | 32   | 0.81  |   1   |   3   |  <--- auto-repeats...
| 4      | 2     | 33   | 0.87  |   2   |   2   |
```

Is this a built in join/merge-type, or requiring a loop of some sort?

{This is just false data, but dfs are over 1000 rows...}

Current code is a simple outer merge, but doesn't provide the fill/repeat to end:

`df = main.merge(df_coords, left_index=True, right_index = True, how='outer')` and just gives NaNs.

I've checked around:
[Merge two python pandas data frames of different length but keep all rows in output data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086881/merge-two-python-pandas-data-frames-of-different-length-but-keep-all-rows-in-out)
[pandas: duplicate rows from small dataframe to large based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573267/pandas-duplicate-rows-from-small-dataframe-to-large-based-on-cell-value)

and it feels like this could be an arguement somewhere in a merge function... but I can't find it.
Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat `df2` until it's as long as `df1`, then `reset_index` and `merge`:

```
new_len = round(len(df1)/len(df2))
repeated = (pd.concat([df2] * new_len)
              .reset_index()
              .drop(["index"], 1)
              .iloc[:len(df1)])

repeated
   x  y
0  1  3
1  2  2
2  1  6
3  1  3
4  2  2

df1.merge(repeated, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
   Wafer  Chip  Value   x  y
0      1    32    0.99  1  3
1      1    33    0.89  2  2
2      1    39    0.96  1  6
3      2    32    0.81  1  3
4      2    33    0.87  2  2
```

A little hacky, but it should work.

Note: I'm assuming your `Index` column is not actually a column, but is in fact intended to represent the data frame index.  I'm making this assumption because you refer to `left_index`/`right_index` args in your `merge()` code.  If `Index` is actually its own column, this code will basically work, you'll just need to `drop` `Index` as well if you don't want it in the final `df`.

Comment: That works, thanks! I would love to know if there is a more built in way, but that's great for now, cheers.

Comment: Regarding your edit: correct. In my actual code i've used `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a left join on the value of `df1["Index"]` **mod** the length of `df2["Index"]`:

```
# Creating Modular Index values on df1
n = df2.shape[0]
df1["Modular Index"] = df1["Index"].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)%n))

# Merging dataframes
df_combined = df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on="Modular Index", right_on="Index")

# Dropping unnecessary columns
df_combined = df_combined.drop(["Modular Index", "Index_y"], axis=1)
```

```
print(df_combined)

0 Index_x Wafer Chip Value  x  y
0       0     1   32  0.99  1  3
1       1     1   33  0.89  2  2
2       2     1   39  0.96  1  6
3       3     2   32  0.81  1  3
4       4     2   33  0.87  2  2
```